# Wine1.7 Partially Working With Eve Online

Tags: wine

Since there were some updates to my machine I haven't been able to launch Eve Online into the game any more. I can load the login screen from the launcher, and even log in, but then when the game is supposed to launch after login, it doesn't. I don't really know what to do. I've tried removing wine1.7, and installing wine1.6. This doesn't work. I've tried re-installing wine1.7 and this also doesn't work. What do I do?